# How to move many files in multiple different directories (on Linux)

Tags: regex, linux, file, bash, shell

My problem is that I have too many files in single directory. I cannot "`ls`" the directory, cos is too large. I need to move all files in better directory structure.

I'm using the last 3 digits from ID as folders in reverse way.

For example ID `2018972` will gotta go in `/2/7/9/img_2018972.jpg`.

I've created the directories, but now I need help with bash script. I know the IDs, there are in range `1,300,000 - 2,000,000`. But I can't handle regular expressions.

I wan't to move all files like this:

```
/images/folder/img_2018972.jpg -> /images/2/7/9/img_2018972.jpg
```

I will appreciate any help on this subject. Thanks!

Comment: you can emulate `ls` using something like; `for f in *; do printf -- "%s\t" "$f"; done` and `ls -1` with `for f in *; do printf -- "%s\n" "$f"; done` . `ls` fails here because of `ARG_MAX`, maximum arguments limit.

Comment: Thanks for replays, I forgot to mention, that in the folder I have  more jpg files with the same file name structure, but with "_220, _380" at the end.. like: img_1234567_220.jpg.

Comment: do you mean that you don't want to match those ? or is the answer ok ?

Comment: I want to match them too, just I'm not sure if the answers are OK.I can make several bash scripts for any image size that I have, because they are not just two.. in fact they are (_80,_125,_220,_340,_380,_620). I would use your solution, but can you tell me is it safe? :)

Comment: with @kev 's answer any filename ending in **three digits** followed by `.jpg` will be matched. with my answer any filename ending with `.jpg` will be matched, and the three last **letters** will be extracted. kev's will not match \_80, and wont move those files (as '_' is not a digit/in range 0-9), while mine will match it, and move it in `/images/0/8/_/`. I can alter that behavior if not desired.

Comment: cOOkiemo5ter, thank you for your help, can you please alter script, to match _80,_125,_220,_340,_380,_620 and move them too?

Comment: \_125, \_220, .. etc .. will work fine, it's just \_80 that will not. fixing it now. In the case of `_80` the new dir should be `/images/0/8/` right ?

Comment: No, img_1234567_80.jpg should be in same folder as image without _80 -> img_1234567.jpg. Ex. /7/6/5/img_1234567_80.jpg

Comment: oh, so you want to skip _xxx altogether

Comment: edited my answer, please see the assumption that I make, it should do what you asked.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is exactly what I need. I've started bash script in the folder and now I'm waiting to see, can the miracle happen? :) I've tested script in small folder with few images and works great. Thanks! Thank you for all your help guys! This is my first question here and you are so helpful! Best wishes to all. I will write back, when the script is over, to tell you the result.

Comment: what filesytem are you using? ext4 is much better with many files than ext2/3. Also xfs is an option to try with linux. btw ls on many distros is doing sorting by default so you may try disabling such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT*: after explainations in comments the following assumptions exists:

- filenames are in the form of `img_<id>.jpg` or `img_<id>_<size>.jpg`
- the new dir is the *reverse* order of the three last digits of the **id**

using Bash:

```
for file in /images/folder/*.jpg; do 
    fname="${file%.*}"      # remove extension and _<size>
    [[ "$fname" =~ img_[0-9]+_[0-9]+$ ]] && fname="${fname%_*}"

    last0="${fname: -1:1}"  # last letter/digit
    last1="${fname: -2:1}"  # last but one letter/digit
    last2="${fname: -3:1}"  # last but two letter/digit

    newdir="/images/$last0/$last1/$last2"
    # optionally check if the new dir exists, if not create it
    [[ -d "$newdir" ]] || mkdir -p "$newdir"

    mv "$file" "$newdir"
done
```

if `*` can't handle it (although I think `*` in a for loop has no limits),
use `find` as suggested by @Michał Kosmulski in the comments

```
while read -r; do 
    fname="${REPLY%.*}"     # remove extension and _<size>
    [[ "$fname" =~ img_[0-9]+_[0-9]+$ ]] && fname="${fname%_*}"

    last0="${fname: -1:1}"  # last letter/digit
    last1="${fname: -2:1}"  # last but one letter/digit
    last2="${fname: -3:1}"  # last but two letter/digit

    newdir="/images/$last0/$last1/$last2"
    # optionally check if the new dir exists, if not create it
    [[ -d "$newdir" ]] || mkdir -p "$newdir"

    mv "$REPLY" "$newdir"
done < <(find /images/folder/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg")
```

Comment: The shell expansion of `/images/folder/*.jpg` will probably not work due to the huge number of files, but you can replace the for-loop with `find /images/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' | while read; do <do stuff based on $REPLY>; done`

Comment: added that option, although I think `*` has no limit when used in a loop. there are limits when used as argument to a function/script; `ARG_MAX` that is.

Comment: Thanks for great help. I have used second version of script (where we use find as suggested by @Michał Kosmulski in the comments). It works great, even in folder they are so many files, that I can't even count... I suppose over 2 - 3 million files. Let's see when it completes. Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
find /images/folder -type f -maxdepth 1 | while read file
do
filelen=${#file}
((rootn=$filelen-5))
((midn=$filelen-6))
((topn=$filelen-7))
root=${file:$rootn:1}
mid=${file:$midn:1}
top=${file:$topn:1}
mkdir -p /images/${root}/${mid}/${top}
mv $file /images/${root}/${mid}/${top}
done
```

Comment: I think this is too much work calculating offsets. also in UNIX and UNIX like OSes, filenames are allowed to contain anything. You better add some quotes there, and look up the `-r` switch to `read`. Try `help read` in your shell ;)